# Change order ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, choicefield

How to manually change order in choice field from model?

For example:

This code :

```
ModelChoiceField(queryset=SomeModel.objects.order_by('SomeField'))
```

give me:

```
'a_somevalue'
'b_somevalue'
'c_somevalue'
'd_somevalue'
```

This code :

```
ModelChoiceField(queryset=SomeModel.objects.order_by('-SomeField'))
```

give me:

```
'd_somevalue'
'c_somevalue'
'b_somevalue'
'a_somevalue'
```

but how to do this:

```
'c_somevalue'
'a_somevalue'
'd_somevalue'
'b_somevalue'
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Add another field that describes the ordering you want, and order by it.

Comment: Yes, I know ... I thought about this, but it is not solution this problem, it's just skipping of it.

Comment: You want an arbitrary order. This is how you implement an arbitrary order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.QuerySet.extra):

```
q = Entry.objects.extra(select={'my_sort_field': 
                                "some think like ___
                                    FIND_IN_SET( left(somefield,1),'c,a,d,b')  "})
q = q.extra(order_by = ['my_sort_field'])
```

But, if was this my model, I will create a new field intended for sort operations and I will keep it overwriting save() method or by signals.